# UTF-8 in XML constructed using Java

Tags: java, xml, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

Using Java I am constructing some XML. In the XML some nodes may have values which are in Korean language or some other language. After constructing, how do I make sure that my whole XML is in UTF-8 encoding? Do I need to explicitly change the string to UTF-8 by using something like:

```
string = new String(s.getBytes(), "UTF-8");
```

Or will the whole string be automatically in UTF-8?

Also if I get some XML with some UTF-8 like this `<name>[B@19821f<name>`, how do I know that `[B@19821f` is a UTF-8 of some Korean word?

Comment: Kozlov, remember to accept some answers to your other questions. Surely somebody has helped you out with an answer to some of those questions ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A string contains characters. The encoding is irrelevant until you transform the string into bytes. This happens when you call `String.getBytes()`, or when you write the String to a stream (file, socket, whatever).

Make sure you use an `OutputStreamWriter` to write your XML string, and that you specify UTF-8 as charset when constructing this `OutputStreamWriter`. If you're using a dedicated marshalling API like JAXB, set the appropriate property so that the UTF-8 encoding is used, and the generated XML contains its encoding (in the `<?xml ...?>` header) . Without knowing which API you're using to generate your XML string, it's hard to be more helpful.

Comment: Hi Thanks a lot , i was using
ByteArrayOutputStream byteOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
PrintWriter pr = new PrintWriter(byteOut);
I think 
ByteArrayOutputStream byteOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  Writer writer = null;
  try {
   writer = new OutputStreamWriter(byteOut, "UTF-8");
  } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
  PrintWriter pr = new PrintWriter(writer); will solve .Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

First: the code you posted to "change the string to UTF8" is wrong. You **never** want to use that (*).

If you parse XML (and the XML is correctly encoded) then you'll already get `String` values in Java that will have the correctly decoded values, so there is nothing else you need to do, just handle the `String` objects as normally.

<sup>(*) there are a few cases where you have to "undo" damage already done where this *might* be useful, but those cases are very rare and then it will usually not work correctly either.</sup>

Comment: Great answer! Do you have any ideas why we see this sort of inappropriate manual encoding/decoding so often? Is it from being fuzzy on the notions of encoders/decoders bound to streams or of abstract Unicode characters, or what? The only times I’ve had to actually do this were on files erroneously containing mixed encoding that varied by line, or when dealing with raw databases. You see the wrong-headed manual approach more often in Python than you do in Java or Perl, but I have seen it crop up in all three, and I wonder why users keeping attempting it.

Comment: As far as I know (and my perception might be wrong) the difference is that in Python (pre-3, can't talk about Perl) a string is actually more of a byte-array than anything else (pretty much the same way it's in C): you'll have to remember to use the correct encoding with it and so on. In Java, however, the encoding of `String` fixed and unchangeable. This means that you can treat it as if it were "pure Unicode" (which of course isn't true any more, since it's UTF-16 now): you only ever need to specify *one* encoding, for the conversion, the other is implicit.